# PostGIS intersect/summary query very slow for particular table

Tags: postgresql, postgis

**Edited question based on comment by @peter so now the two tables in question are using the same geometry type**

I'm running a query that intersects a table's geometry with a generic input geometry and then summarizes the results based on a specific attribute.

The reason I'm suspicious (and frustrated) with this particular query is that I  can run the exact same query on a different table that is 40x the size and it takes 1/100 of the time.

I'm puzzled because I'm very happy with the speed (~400ms) that this query has on a large table with 1.3M records. However, on a particular table with 30,000 records the query takes 40+ seconds to complete.

Here's the query:

```
WITH input_geom AS (
    SELECT ST_Transform(
        ST_SetSRID(
            ST_GeomFromGeoJSON(
                '{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[-91.865616,47.803339],[-91.830597,47.780274],[-91.810341,47.817404],[-91.865616,47.803339]]]}'
            ), 4326
        ), 26915
    ) AS geom
)


-- find total area and proportion for each type
SELECT
    attr,
    total_area_summtable AS area,
    total_area_summtable / buff_area.area_sqm AS percent
FROM
(-- group by attribute and buffer
    SELECT
        attr,
        sum(area_sqm) AS total_area_summtable
    FROM
    (-- find intersected area of each type
        -- Clip ownership by input geom
        SELECT
            %attr% AS attr,
            CASE
                -- speed intersection calculation by using summary table
                -- geom when it covers the entire buffer
                -- otherwise use intersection of geometries
                WHEN ST_CoveredBy(input_geom.geom, summtable.geom) THEN ST_Area(input_geom.geom)
                ELSE ST_Area(ST_Multi(ST_Intersection(input_geom.geom,summtable.geom)))
            END AS area_sqm
        FROM input_geom
        INNER JOIN %table% AS summtable ON ST_Intersects(input_geom.geom, summtable.geom)

    ) AS summtable_inter
    -- group by type
    GROUP BY attr
) AS summtable_area,
(-- find total area for the buffer
    SELECT
        ST_Area(ST_Collect(geom)) AS area_sqm
    FROM input_geom
) AS buff_area
```

That produces results like this:

```
attr  area              percent  
6     17106063.3199902  0.0630578194718625  
8     41892903.9272884  0.154429170732226  
2     4441738.70688669  0.016373513430921  
....
```

Here are the Explain Analyze results for this query:

```
    Nested Loop  (cost=31.00..31.34 rows=9 width=23) (actual time=49042.306..49042.309 rows=5 loops=1)
  Output: mown.owner_desc, (sum(CASE WHEN ((input_geom_1.geom @ mown.geom) AND _st_coveredby(input_geom_1.geom, mown.geom)) THEN st_area(input_geom_1.geom) ELSE st_area(st_multi(st_intersection(input_geom_1.geom, mown.geom))) END)), ((sum(CASE WHEN ((input (...)
  CTE input_geom
    ->  Result  (cost=0.00..0.01 rows=1 width=0) (actual time=0.002..0.002 rows=1 loops=1)
          Output: '01030000202369000001000000040000003D484506D9D92141B7A4EA61F6325441A3BEFDC8A2EE2141E731F0497F305441774E0C95FEF9214173B409BA8C3454413D484506D9D92141B7A4EA61F6325441'::geometry
  ->  Aggregate  (cost=0.02..0.06 rows=1 width=32) (actual time=0.035..0.036 rows=1 loops=1)
        Output: st_area(st_collect(input_geom.geom))
        ->  CTE Scan on input_geom  (cost=0.00..0.02 rows=1 width=32) (actual time=0.005..0.006 rows=1 loops=1)
              Output: input_geom.geom
  ->  HashAggregate  (cost=30.96..31.05 rows=9 width=18085) (actual time=49042.264..49042.266 rows=5 loops=1)
        Output: mown.owner_desc, sum(CASE WHEN ((input_geom_1.geom @ mown.geom) AND _st_coveredby(input_geom_1.geom, mown.geom)) THEN st_area(input_geom_1.geom) ELSE st_area(st_multi(st_intersection(input_geom_1.geom, mown.geom))) END)
        Group Key: mown.owner_desc
        ->  Nested Loop  (cost=4.32..25.34 rows=18 width=18085) (actual time=3.304..791.829 rows=39 loops=1)
              Output: input_geom_1.geom, mown.owner_desc, mown.geom
              ->  CTE Scan on input_geom input_geom_1  (cost=0.00..0.02 rows=1 width=32) (actual time=0.001..0.003 rows=1 loops=1)
                    Output: input_geom_1.geom
              ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on public.gap_stewardship_2008_all_ownership_types mown  (cost=4.32..25.30 rows=2 width=18053) (actual time=3.299..791.762 rows=39 loops=1)
                    Output: mown.gid, mown.wetland_ty, mown.county, mown.name, mown.unit, mown.owner, mown.owner_ver1, mown.owner_desc, mown.owner_name, mown.agency, mown.agncy_ver1, mown.agency_nam, mown.new_manage, mown.name_manag, mown.comments, mown.or (...)
                    Recheck Cond: (input_geom_1.geom && mown.geom)
                    Filter: _st_intersects(input_geom_1.geom, mown.geom)
                    Rows Removed by Filter: 208
                    Heap Blocks: exact=142
                    ->  Bitmap Index Scan on gap_stewardship_2008_all_ownership_types_geom_idx  (cost=0.00..4.31 rows=5 width=0) (actual time=0.651..0.651 rows=247 loops=1)
                          Index Cond: (input_geom_1.geom && mown.geom)
Planning time: 1.245 ms
Execution time: 49046.184 ms
```

Here is the SQL to recreate the tables in question:
Slow table (50,000 rows):

```
CREATE TABLE public.gap_stewardship_2008_all_ownership_types
(
  gid integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('gap_stewardship_2008_all_ownership_types_gid_seq'::regclass),
  wetland_ty character varying(50),
  county character varying(50),
  name character varying(50),
  unit character varying(50),
  owner smallint,
  owner_ver1 smallint,
  owner_desc character varying(50),
  owner_name character varying(50),
  agency smallint,
  agncy_ver1 smallint,
  agency_nam character varying(50),
  new_manage smallint,
  name_manag character varying(50),
  comments character varying(100),
  origin character varying(50),
  area numeric,
  acres numeric,
  perfeet numeric,
  perimeter numeric,
  km2 numeric,
  shape_leng numeric,
  shape_area numeric,
  geom geometry(MultiPolygon,26915),
  CONSTRAINT gap_stewardship_2008_all_ownership_types_pkey PRIMARY KEY (gid)
)
```

Fast table (1,300,000 rows):

```
CREATE TABLE public.nwi_combine
(
  id integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('"NWI_combine_AOI_id_seq"'::regclass),
  geom geometry(MultiPolygon,26915),
  attribute character varying(254),
  wetland_ty character varying(254),
  acres numeric,
  hgm_code character varying(254),
  hgm_desc character varying(254),
  spcc_desc character varying(254),
  cow_class1 character varying(254),
  circ39_cla bigint,
  hgm_ll_des character varying(254),
  shape_leng numeric,
  shape_area numeric,
  nwi_code character varying(254),
  new_cow character varying(254),
  system character varying(254),
  subsystem character varying(254),
  class1 character varying(254),
  subclass1 character varying(254),
  class2 character varying(254),
  subclass2 character varying(254),
  wreg character varying(254),
  soilm character varying(254),
  spec_mod1 character varying(254),
  spec_mod2 character varying(254),
  circ39 character varying(254),
  old_cow character varying(254),
  mnwet character varying(254),
  circ39_com bigint,
  CONSTRAINT "NWI_combine_AOI_pkey" PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
```

Each of these tables has a GIST index on the geometry field.

Does anyone have any idea what could be contributing to such a difference?

Comment: Good suggestion. Not sure how to format that any better, though.

Comment: Are you aware that the geometry types in both tables differ?

Comment: It is the evaluation of the functions in the `CASE` expression that take up most of the time. I don't know PostGIS, so I can't say how that could be improved

Comment: @peter - I didn't pick up on that detail. Thank you.

Comment: I updated the question so that now the tables in question are using the same geometry type; problem persists, however...

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - Thanks for reviewing the explain for that information. I'm not necessarily looking to improve the CASE statement since it works very fast on most tables (all but the one in question).